# How is it possible that a converging lens can form a virtual image if its function is to make the light converges?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

If the function of a converging lens is to do the light converge, how it can form a virtual image, which as far as I know is formed when the light diverges ?

I have another question, that may seems dumb for you, but I really have problems trying to understand real and virtual images, maybe because I´m taking the optics lab when I haven't taken the corresponding theoretical class:

The image form by the objetive of a rudimentary mycroscop and a refractor telescope needs to be real in order to the ocular can amplify it ? If I set the object whithin the focal lenght of the objective, a virtual image is formed, can the ocular formed and image of this virtual image?

Comment: The virtual image may be formed if the light rays change their direction. Whether it is a converging or a diverging lense is not the reason for forming virtual images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which as far as I know is formed when the light diverges?

The lens tries its best and makes the light **less** divergent but is not powerful enough to make it convergent.

[image]

What you are asking for is a virtual intermediate image to the left of the first lens light from which is focussed a second lens.
Here is a possible arrangement of lenses where the first lens produces a virtual image and the final image is at infinity.

[image]

This is the ray diagram for a Galilean telescope which is much shorter than a conventional refracting telescope where the intermediate image is never formed and is said to be a virtual object for the second lens..

[image]